# Setting up enumerate list with custom titles

Tags: lists, enumerate

How do I change the beginning of each elements of an `enumerate` list. I have a list with 3 elements, all of them appearing as `1.` `2.` etc.

How do I change that to become

```
Example 1: 
Example 2:
```

etc ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

If the overhang to the left margin is no issue, `label={Example \arabic*:}` is perhaps the answer to your question then.

If you need more than this list over and over again, then clone the `enumerate` list and use special settings then:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newlist{examplelist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[examplelist,1]{label={Example \arabic*:},labelwidth={40pt},leftmargin=*}


\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{enumerate}[label={Example \arabic*:},labelwidth={40pt}]
\item First
\item Second
\end{enumerate}

\begin{examplelist}
\item First
\item Second
\end{examplelist}


\end{document}
```

See the screen shot -- the basic difference is `leftmargin=*`!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Three other variants:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{enumerate}[label={Example \arabic*. },wide = 0pt, font =\itshape]
\item A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example.
\item Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[resume*,wide =\parindent]
\item A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example.
\item Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[resume*, leftmargin = 1.5em, font =\itshape]
\item A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example.
\item Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example. Another example.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]